# How do I know if ARM's XN (execute never) bit support is enabled on my system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I am working on a linux embedded system with an ARM cortex A5 processor and a linux kernel version somewhere around 3.13.9. How can I verify whether XN bit support is enabled?

Also, I know that the ARMv7 architecture supports it, but what is needed from the kernel to use it?

As far as I know, /proc/cpuinfo does not have a feature flag for ARM xn support (although Intel does have a flag for nx).

Also, it seems that newer ARMs have UXN and PXN. How does this relate to the older XN?

It would be nice to see maybe see page tables with the bit marked, or registers showing the NX bit = 1. Also, is there an easy to run, say, ret2usr attack to verify protection? Any other verification methods are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just map something without `PROT_EXEC` and see if you can call it?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I verify whether XN bit support is enabled?

According to the ARM manual [5.5.3. Execute never bits](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/CACHFICI.html), XN is in [c1 Control Register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/CACHFICI.html). Userland (Exception Level 0) cannot access those fields in the configurations I am aware of.

You have two or three choices (or maybe one). First, if running as a privileged process (Exception Level 1 or above), then just read the c1 register.

Second, see if the feature can be queried using a `HWCAP`. Here is Torvald's [`asm/hwcaps.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/hwcap.h), but I don't see a `HWCAP_XN` or similar. `HWCAP_IWMMXT` may be it but I cannot find what the define represents.

`HWCAP` is the easiest path because you only need to do the following (but it does not appear to be available to you):

```
if ((getauxval(AT_HWCAP) & HWCAP_XN) != 0)
    return true;
```

Since the second choice is not available, you can perform a feature probe. I call them `SIGILL` probes because you are often probing for ISA support, like NEON using a NEON load. If you catch a `SIGILL` you know the processor does not support NEON.

In your case, you should perform what @o11c suggests in the comment. You should allocate a page, set `PROT_EXEC`, and see if you can write to it. If you cannot write to it, then `write` will fail with `errno=EPERM` or you will catch an exception. If the `write` fails then you mark the NX feature as available.

I don't have a feature probe handy for `XN` (I've never needed it), but I can show you what a `SIGILL` probe looks like when [probing for ARMv7 support](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/neon_simd.cpp).

Also be careful of probes on Apple machines. Apple has a bug that affects register or process state after taking a `longjmp`, and it will trash things something awful. Never probe on Apple platforms. Just return false for the feature.

---

```
extern "C" {
    typedef void (*SigHandler)(int);

    static jmp_buf s_jmpSIGILL;
    static void SigIllHandler(int)
    {
        longjmp(s_jmpSIGILL, 1);
    }
}

bool CPU_ProbeARMv7()
{
    // longjmp and clobber warnings. Volatile is required.
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/7721854
    volatile bool result = true;

    volatile SigHandler oldHandler = signal(SIGILL, SigIllHandler);
    if (oldHandler == SIG_ERR)
        return false;

    volatile sigset_t oldMask;
    if (sigprocmask(0, NULLPTR, (sigset_t*)&oldMask))
        return false;

    if (setjmp(s_jmpSIGILL))
        result = false;
    else
    {
        // ARMv7 added movt and movw
        int a;
        asm volatile("movw %0,%1 \n"
                     "movt %0,%1 \n"
                     : "=r"(a) : "i"(0x1234));
        result = (a == 0x12341234);
    }

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, (sigset_t*)&oldMask, NULLPTR);
    signal(SIGILL, oldHandler);
    return result;
}
```